# sas delete specific values from dataset and replace with missing

Tags: replace, sas

If this is my dataset

```
 Col1    Col2   Col3
 6.102   9.431  7.250 
 6.228   5.185  a.b 
 a.b     9.507  8.694
 7.439   7.782  5.959 
 9.589   a.b    8.986 
 5.695   9.706  5.900 
 7.453   a.b    a.b 
 a.b     9.475  8.124 
 9.130   6.684  a.b
 8.860   a.b    6.444 
 5.274   5.951  7.034 
 a.b     8.778  a.b 
 a.b     8.163  9.028
```

How do I delete cells with **a.b** so that my final dataset looks like this

```
 Col1    Col2   Col3
 6.102   9.431  7.250 
 6.228   5.185   
         9.507  8.694
 7.439   7.782  5.959 
 9.589          8.986 
 5.695   9.706  5.900 
 7.453   
         9.475  8.124 
 9.130   6.684  
 8.860          6.444 
 5.274   5.951  7.034 
         8.778   
         8.163  9.028
```

This is what I did so far.

```
/* Replace a.d with missing */
    DATA WORK.DATA1;
      set WORK.DATA1;
      if Col1=Col2=Col3="a.b" then call missing(of Col1 Col2 Col3);
    run;
```

But this dosent seem to work. Any suggestions would be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where did the 'a.b' strings come from? Why did you make the variables character when it appears you only want to store numbers?  If you had made the variables as numeric the values of "a.b" would have automatically been converted to missing since that string does not represent a valid number.

Answer (score 2):

You will want to test each column separately:

```
if col1 = "a.b" then call missing(col1);
if col2 = "a.b" then call missing(col2);
if col3 = "a.b" then call missing(col3);
```

For the case of having more than three columns, specify the columns as elements of an array.

```
array cols col:;
do _n_ = 1 to dim(cols);
  if cols(_n_) = "a.b" then call missing (cols(_n_));
end;
```

The issue of the columns being character values means a conversion to a numeric values is necessary.  The missing assignment will be a side effect of the `input` function not being able to convert `a.b` to a number.

```
array chars col1-col3;
array nums  x1-x3;

do _n_ = 1  to dim(chars);
  nums(_n_) = input (chars(_n_), ?? best12.);
end;
```

The `??` feature of `input` will prevent messages about invalid conversions (for the `a.b` values) and return a missing value.